# Ubuntu 16.10 DVI only works with VGA adapter

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, hdmi, mesa, dvi

Using Ubuntu 16.10
Intel 945GSE graphics

Using nomodeset in GRUB, the DVI works with a DVI cable and the DVI-HDMI also works, all with a low resolution (i.e. safe-mode)

When NOT using nomodeset, the DVI port only works with a VGA adapter but in full 1920x1080.

I want to use the DVI port as DVI or with an HDMI adapter so that I can connect to a TV to use Kobi with an iptv subscription.

Steps to try and fix:
Tried with a different monitor
Installed and used the INTEL GRAPHICS UPDATE TOOL FOR LINUX* OS V2.0.4
played with xrandr

Comment: note: tried with 32bit Ubuntu and 32bit Lubuntu 
Intel ATOM N270

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it**, thanks to https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=235180 just had to play with xrandr some more...now need to make this fix automatic on boot, later.
Solution:
cvt 1920 1080 59.8

## 1920x1080 59.79 Hz (CVT) hsync: 66.96 kHz; pclk: 172.50 MHz

Modeline "1920x1080_59.80"  172.50  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --newmode 1920x1080_59.80  172.50  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode DVI1 1920x1080
~$ xrandr --output DVI1 --mode 1920x1080